# MVC 3 running IIS 5.1 does not work with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, windows-xp

I am running MVC 3 on Visual Studio 2010 using IIS 5.1 and Framework 4.0.

It works fine using Visual Studio built in web server but as soon as I start using IIS 5.1 it does not work.

I also added application extension mapping (.*) using `aspnet_isapi.dll` but as soon as I add that, Visual Studio 2010 does not even let me debug the application and throws an error saying the resource cannot be found.

I have been pulling out my  hair for 8 hours. If this does not work,  I would have to revert back to ASP.NET web forms.

Could anyone please please help me?

Comment: pls do not revert to web forms, help is on its way. :P

Comment: [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) is a in-depth, guide on how to install an MVC site on IIS.

Comment: but this article goes through IIS 6, you think it would work the same way with IIS 5.1 please?

Comment: Check this: http://www.dotnetacademy.blogspot.in/2012/01/setup-aspnet-mvc3-on-iis-5.html

Comment: what i have found out in MVC is, if i use the Intranet template and do the settings in IIS as suggested in the website recommmended by yasser, it all works. but if i use the internet template and do the same settings in IIS as suggessted, the visual studio does not even let me run the application. this is the erro that it throws: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that MVC does not like dot in the name of an application. So if it's like `test.mvc`, it will throw an error. After removing the dot, it all works.